# How to configure redis rdb persistence?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

My team is switching from a single instance redis to a cluster of three in order to be more resilient.
We sadly faced a crash when migrating and that raised questions.

Here is our configuration :

- We use the bitnami helm chart : https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/redis
- We have 3 replicas

  - 2Gi per pod
  - maxmemory of 1800mb
  - persistence of 2Gi
- maxmemory policy : allkeys-lfu

When it crashed, log indicates that it could not write to disk "No space left on device".

We had the same configuration on a testing environment, we filled it and it did not failed. But it failed on production environment. Is there an explanation for this ?

When looking at some documentation, it says that the persistence should be 3 times the ram memory, can you explain why ?

If you have any other advice on that matter, I would gladly read them.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to persist Redis data set, the disk size should be at least 2 times the size of the data set (might not be the same size of the memory size, since the memory size is not the same as the RDB/AOF file size).

Because when Redis does a new dump, it creates a new RDB file, and writes data set to it. Finally it renames the new file to the original RDB file, when it finishes dumping. So when Redis does a dump, it needs at least 2 times the size of data set, i.e. 2 RDB files.

Also, if your Redis instance has a replica, when the replica does a full sync, it needs to create a new RDB file, which also needs disk space, and send the whole file to replica. However, high version of Redis can use diskless replication, which does not need to dump a file to disk.